# A 32Bit porcess can not access modules of a 64bit process

Tags: c#, windows, exception, process

I am trying to execute a cmd process in my c# code. For most of the application it is working smoothly. But a single task i am getting `A 32Bit  porcess can not access modules of a 64bit process` . i am not trying to access a `MainModule` Property. And the strange thing is When running with `IIS Express` the above Exception is not being thrown. This is being thrown only when i host my code in IIS. 
Below is the code that i using for executing a process

```
public static int RunProcess(string startInfoArg)
    {
        int exitcode = 1;
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = startInfoArg;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            exitcode = process.ExitCode;
        }
        return exitcode;
    }
```

Comment: How is the app pool for this app in IIS express configured?  There is a propoerty you can find in the `advanced settings` page that says `enable 32-bit processes`.  If that is flagged, then your app pool is running your app as a 32-bit process which is why your function is failing.

Comment: @SteveMitcham it is set to true

Comment: If you uncheck it, it will run as 64bit